# Rails: RSPEC test for updating active record entry is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have two models: `Draft` and `Pick`.  I want the `Draft`'s ActiveRecord column `current_pick` to increase by 1 after a `Pick` is created.

Inside Pick, I have a method that increase `draft.current_pick` by 1:

```
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :draft

after_save :advance_draft

def advance_draft
    draft.updraft
end
```

Inside `draft`, updraft is:

```
def updraft
    self.current_pick += 1
end
```

My test to ensure the current_pick is being increased by one is:

```
    it 'should run the advance_draft method after creating' do
        team1 = FactoryGirl.create(:team)
        team2 = FactoryGirl.create(:team_two)
        cam = FactoryGirl.create(:player)
        draft = FactoryGirl.create(:two_team_draft)
        pick = Pick.create(:player_id => cam.id, :team_id => draft.team_at(draft.current_pick).id, :draft_id => draft.id, :draft_position => draft.current_pick)
        draft.draft_position.should eq 2
    end
```

The `pick` and `draft` are being created in the test but the updraft method is not being called on the correct `draft` because the `pick.draft.draft_position` remains at 1 after the `pick` has been created. (it should increase to 2).

Here is my schema:

```
create_table "drafts", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "draft_position"
    t.integer  "number_of_teams"
    t.integer  "PPTD"
    t.integer  "PPR"
    t.integer  "current_pick",            default: 1
end

create_table "picks", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "player_id"
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "draft_id"
    t.integer  "draft_position"
end
```

My question is, how do I properly increase the `pick.draft.current_pick` inside my test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do 2 things, use `increment!` when updating the count to increment the value and save the record, and `reload` the object you're looking at, since its database representation has changed since it was created.

```
def updraft
  increment!(:current_pick)
end
```

This will update the `current_pick` and save the object in one shot.

```
it 'should run the advance_draft method after creating' do
  # ... setup
  draft.reload.draft_position.should eq 2
end
```

Now, instead of using the instance of `draft` that was created before the modification occurred, it's using a version current with the database.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea reload even existed.

Comment: I added the code as you suggested but the problem is persisting.

Comment: Added draft.save after draft.updraft and the reload method worked as it should!!!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Whoops, yeah you definitely need to save.  I suggested the wrong increment method!  `increment!` will increment the value and save for you.  I used the non-bang version `increment` that does not save.  Give that a try if you want to simplify.